# grails call hibernate update

Tags: grails

Have another question related to [Grails issue with unique/save/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550277/grails-issue-with-unique-save-update).

is there any way to avoid call def bookInstance.get(bookList.id[it]) ? for example, I still want to overwrite the exist data in DB, but I don't want to load exist one from DB, So i call def bookInstance = new Book() bookInstance.id=XXX bookInstance.save()

This does not work, because gorm take it as a new Object, is there any way to force update exist one? like call hibernateSession.update

Answer (score 1):

Loading the instance shouldn't be very expensive, so you're probably prematurely optimizing. But you can use `executeUpdate` to update data without retrieving it first. For example if your Book class looks like this:

```
class Book {
    String author
    String title
}
```

then you can update it like this:

```
Book.executeUpdate(
    'update Book b set b.author=:author, b.title=:title where b.id=:id',
    [author: params.author, title: params.author, id: params.id])
```

Comment: The reason for me don't want to loading instance is:when there is one-to-many mapping in domain objects, if loading it from DB, I need to clear all the one-to-many data before I call ***.properties=params. I want to build up a common infrastructure for my team, so I want to remove any unnecessary code. Your suggestion is greate , but may introduce more code.